# String to date formatting

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string of the following format:
x = '2018-02-15-11'

I need to convert this to a date format. I have tried:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import time
from datetime import datetime

dhs = '2018-02-15-11'
x = datetime.strptime(dhs, '%Y-%M-%d-%H')
print x
```

However, the output is

```
2018-01-15 11:02:00
```

I need the output in the format (as date object):

```
2018-01-15-11
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `M` is minutes, and month is `1` by default, as you haven't specified it.

Comment: Doesn't your string start out as `'2018-02-15-11'` ? Why do you need to convert it at all?

Comment: try changing %H to %k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there could be a mistake on your part, you have used `%Y-%M-%d-%H` where `%M` indicates *minutes*, not *month*. But according to the look, it should be `%m` i.e. *month*.

Answering your original question, the format specifiers for `strftime` (datetime to string) and `strptime` (string to datetime) are the same. So you can use `datetime.datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H')` like:

```
In [47]: dhs = '2018-02-15-11'
    ...: x = datetime.datetime.strptime(dhs, '%Y-%m-%d-%H')
    ...: print(x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H'))
    ...: 
2018-02-15-11
```

I've used `%m` instead of `%M` here. If you are really sure about this, use `%M` if you want.

N.B: You are getting same string you've started with.